# WSS-Password Type in soap request using Citrus

Tags: soapui, citrus-framework

I need to send soap request to automate my tests using Citrus framework. But when I send the request, it returns "Invalid username or password"

[Soap response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqebN.png)

I tried sending the same using SoapUI and it works fine since it sends the password type as text via properties.

[Password type in soapUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUcU1.png)

The problem I have here is setting the "WSS-Password Type" in citrus.I had set the username and password using the citrus documentation but I didn't find how to set up the password type as text.

citrus-context.xml

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>

    <citrus-ws:client id="todoListClient"
                      request-url="soapURL"
 message-sender="basicAuthClient"/>

<bean id="basicAuthClient" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
  <property name="authScope">
      <bean class="org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope">
        <constructor-arg value="host"/>
        <constructor-arg value="port"/>
        <constructor-arg value=""/>
        <constructor-arg value="basic"/>
      </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="credentials">
    <bean class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
        <constructor-arg value="username"/>
        <constructor-arg value="password"/>

    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Help me to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses basic authentication instead of WSSecurity. You have to configure a client interceptor for WSSecurity as follows:

```
<citrus-ws:client id="todoListClient"
                  request-url="http://localhost:8080/services/ws/todolist"
                  interceptor="wss4jSecurityInterceptor"/>

<bean id="wss4jSecurityInterceptor"
   class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="securementActions" value="Timestamp UsernameToken"/>
    <property name="securementUsername" value="admin"/>
    <property name="securementPassword" value="secret"/>
</bean>
```

The Wss4jSecurityInterceptor class has a property named "securementPasswordType" that you can set.

Also see the Citrus sample project https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-soap-wssecurity

Comment: That works to send the request. But getting error in receiving response. ERROR jSecurityInterceptor| Could not secure response: Unknown password type encoding: PasswordType; nested exception is org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Unknown password type encoding: PasswordType
org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecuritySecurementException: Unknown password type encoding: PasswordType;

Comment: Somehow I made the workaround by setting another property as <property name="secureResponse" value="false"/> . Appreciate your help. Thanks.